# Installing asp.net website template in VS2008

Tags: asp.net, installation

i have just receive an aspx website template, how do i install it in vs2008?
it does not come with instructions on how to install it, but it has these files;

1. MyTemplate.vstemplate
2. all .aspx and .aspx.cs files

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place the template in a directory that Visual Studio recognizes as a template directory.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx) MSDN page (How to: Locate and Organize Project and Item Templates).